# find row with a specific cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which finds a row within an html table whos first column contains a specific value...

```
$('#table tr').find('td:eq(0):contains(' + value + ')').parent();
```

The problem I have is that it returns all rows that have the number 1 in column 0 rather than just the row with 1.  (ie, 1, 15, 21 etc..)

Is there an equivalent 'equals' to the 'contains' part of this search or some other way of doing this?  I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest would be to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) :

```
$('#table tr').filter(function(){
   return $.trim($('td', this).eq(0).text())=="1";
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/sGsEV/)

Comment: need `find` or `nth-child` for all rows  `$('#table tr td:eq(0)')` will return `length=1`

Comment: selector only locates a single `td` , won't loop all rows and look at first `td` in row  http://jsfiddle.net/6HnEy/

Comment: made same mistake numerous times myself

Comment: Thank you!  You've solved the problem, there are a good few people sending mental hugs your way at the moment (it was one of those last minute bugs before a release).  Incidentally the first solution didn't work, it seemed to return the entire table, but the second was spot on.  Thanks again :)